# Flutter PopScope return balck screen on Android back button?

Tags: flutter

Using Flutter 3.16.3 with Dart 3.2.3 DevTools 2.28.4
If I am using PopScope after pressing the 'Press Me' ElevatedButton (before Future is ended), a black screen is displayed.
When using WillPopScope everything is working as expected.

What I would like to accomplished is to use PopScope for displaying progressDialogue on 'Press Me' ElevatedButton so I will work like using WillPopScope.

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

// This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          progressDialogue(context);

          final futureResults = await simulateFuture();
          debugPrint(futureResults);

          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: const Text('Press Me'),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

Future<String> simulateFuture() {
  Completer<String> completer = Completer<String>();

// Simulating an asynchronous task after 2 seconds
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
    // Completing the Future with a value after the task is done
    completer.complete('Simulated Future Result');
  });

  return completer.future;
}

progressDialogue(BuildContext context) {
//set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = const AlertDialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    content: Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
  );
  showDialog(
    //prevent outside touch
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      //prevent Back button press
      //return WillPopScope(onWillPop: () async => false, child: alert);
      return PopScope(onPopInvoked: (didpop) async => false, child: alert);
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour you are getting is exactly what you coded.

In your `ElevatedButton` onPressed, you are calling `Navigator.pop(context);`, that's one.

`PopScope` has two parameters, `canPop` and `onPopInvoked`.

`PopScope` does not work like `WillPopScope`.

`WillPopScope` works by receiving a back navigation event and then deciding if it should proceed or abort. On the other hand

`PopScope` knows beforehand whether or not back navigation should be allowed. This is to accommodate the [Android Predictive Back Feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/predictive-back-gesture)

You can allow or block back navigation with the `canPop` property which is simply a boolean, so it knows beforehand if it should allow back navigation.
By default `canPop` is set to true, which is why you are getting that experience; you are popping twice when there is only one route in the Navigation stack.

`onPopInvoked` is mainly for you to take some action based on whether pop was allowed or not, that is why you have a boolean `didPop` in the callback. It is not for you to return true or false.

You usually do something like:

```
 onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
    if (didPop) {
     // If back navigation was allowed, do nothing.
      return;
    }
     
    // If it was not allowed, do this
    final NavigatorState navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    final bool? shouldPop = await _showBackDialog();
    if (shouldPop ?? false) {
      navigator.pop();
    }
  },
```

If you still need further clarification, this is a good read:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back

You can go directly to this section:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-predictive-back#migrating-a-back-confirmation-dialog

You can also look at the PopScope api
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html

Hope this was helpful

Comment: David, what if we need to run an async function to decide what we will feed the `canPop` with? How can we do this with the new API? I am migrating the app and we have some logic according to which page of the whole flow the user is in. And we do awaited calculations.

Comment: I honestly would need a concrete example to provide an appropriate answer. Maybe ask as a new question and reference it here. @aytunch

Answer (score 1):

There is new property in PopScope named as canPop make it false to prevent back pop

PopScope(
canPop: false, -----> new

)

Comment: This is set to false and yet the back gesture in Android still closes the app.

Comment: You need to set first can pop false and then handle it from popinvoked.

Comment: onPopInvoked has a void return type meaning it cannot veto anything. Either way this answer is at best incomplete or at worst plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with the rough code I just distilled from my app:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  home: NavigatorPopHandler
    onPop: () async {
      if (nav.canPop) {
        nav.pop(false);
      }
      // here you can also do something like:
      return await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
          text: "Are you sure you want to exit this application?",
          actions: [
            // buttons that run SystemNavigator.pop() (exit) or Navigator.of(context).pop(false) (to cancel);
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
    child: Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (_) => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => PopScope(
          canPop: false,
          child: const MyScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```